# Watir loses browser connection after first goto

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am completely new to Watir, trying to work out the basics so we can use it for testing our websites.

The problem is, following the 'Watir in 5 minutes' after I do my first `browser.goto`, I seem to lose connection to the browser window.
The window is still there, but I can no longer "command" it from irb.

I just get this error:

```
C:\>irb
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
irb(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> ie = Watir::Browser.new :ie
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.32.3.0
Listening on port 5555
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..f3e539e40 url="http://localhost:5555/" title="WebDriver"
>
irb(main):003:0> ie.goto "google.com"
=> "http://localhost:5555/"
irb(main):004:0> ie.goto "stackoverflow.com"
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError: Unable to get browser
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:619:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:597:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:103:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/w
atir-webdriver/browser.rb:77:in `goto'
        from (irb):4
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0>
```

I am using Win7 x64 and Ruby x64 BUT a 32bit IE.

Comment: post some code please..do you have more than one windows open of the same browser when running? (although this shouldn't cause a problem)..IS the same problem in every browser? Have you tried FF or Chrome?

Comment: I have updated the code-snippet, but there really isn't any code. I just did a goto, followed by another goto, in the interactive shell.

Comment: IE does some really strange things when you move between sites with different trust levels.  It's a security thing, and depends on the IE version.  In effect I think it closes one and opens another browser instance, on the fly, to prevent access to session cookies etc.  I think that can cause you to get disconnected from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try insuring that all the sites you visit, along with your default homepage, are in the same security zone (e.g. 'trusted') and see if that makes a difference.