# Unable to get browser (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError) only for IE

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, ie-automation

I am facing the following error immediately after launching the browser and visiting URL:

> Unable to get browser (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError) only for IE

My code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new 'ie'
b.goto "google.com"
```

Workaround I have done :

1. Maintained same level for all zones as suggested in [Watir loses browser connection after first goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295448/watir-loses-browser-connection-after-first-goto)
2. Tried with different versions if Selenium IDE servers
3. Tried updating my Watir-webdriver & selenium-webdriver gems

None of my workarounds gave me a positive sign.

Can someone give me a suggestion on how to fix this?

```
Gem Versions:
selenium (0.2.11)
selenium-webdriver (2.39.0, 2.37.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4)
```

Comment: What version of IE? All versions? One particular version? If it's IE11, you may be running into a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6511). The workaround is documented in the [WebDriver project wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration).

Comment: Issue is with all versions of IE @JimEvans

Comment: Issue resolved by setting a registry entry on the target computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. Since mine is a 64 bit machine i have done a registry entry as suggested in https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration